# How can we compare two objects in python & contents of the data with SQL?

Tags: python, android, mysql, object

This is a socket programming in python where python is the server and android is the client. Here I receive QR code data from Android(client-side) which is store in df1 object. Another object is df2 in MySQL database which contains the same QR code data as in df1. Using python, How can I compare these two objects whether their data is same or not ?

`server-side.py`

```
    import socket
    import sys
    import pickle

    def server_program():
        HOST = '192.168.0.113' #this is your localhost
        PORT = 8888

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        #socket.socket: must use to create a socket.
        #socket.AF_INET: Address Format, Internet = IP Addresses.
        #socket.SOCK_STREAM: two-way, connection-based byte streams.
        print('socket created')

        #Bind socket to Host and Port
        try:
            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        except socket.error as err:
            print('Bind Failed, Error Code: ' + str(err[0]) + ', Message: ' + err[1])
            sys.exit()

        print('Socket Bind Success!')


        #listen(): This method sets up and start TCP listener.
        s.listen(10)
        print ('Socket is now listening')


        while 1:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print ('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
            df1 = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            print(df1)
            print('data recieved from client')
            if not df1:
                break
            print("from connected user: " + str(df1))
            df1 = input(' -> ')
            conn.send(df1.encode())
            break
            conn.close()

        s.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        server_program()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem as given below:-

```
 import mysql.connector as mysql # This module is used to connect python with MySQL database 
    import socket
    import sys 
    import json
    #import time

    mydb1=mysql.connect(
            user = 'rajat',
            passwd = 'rajat',
            host = 'localhost',
            database = 'master_database'
            )

    # This is mysql database which is connected with python.
    #Here we need user,host,password and database name to connect with python
    # Its a mysql query which is selecting all fields from table where id is equals to one.

    def server_program():
        HOST = '192.168.0.116' #this is your localhost
        PORT = 8007

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        #socket.socket: must use to create a socket.
        #socket.AF_INET: Address Format, Internet = IP Addresses.
        #socket.SOCK_STREAM: two-way, connection-based byte streams.
        # Binding socket with post and host.

        try:
            s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        except socket.error as err:
            sys.exit()
        #listen(): This method sets up and start TCP listener.
        s.listen(2)
        print ('Socket is now listening')
        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()#Accepting the connection and address of the client
            df7 = conn.recv(1024)#Receiving the data in df7
            df8 = json.loads(df7)
            df2 = list(df8.values())#df7 is in dict format, so we convert it into list and take only values of that data.

            mycursor1=mydb1.cursor()
            mycursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM form_simpleform WHERE id=1")#Used for validating QR code data 
            df3=mycursor1.fetchone()
            if df2 == (list(df3)): #If data is valid, it extracts the valid data of that id and send back the data to the client.
                print('Data of QR Code also Exists')
            else:
                print("Data does not exists")
```